# Adding View to main Window on firs launch in the ipad application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app. in which i am doing that when app is first launch i am adding LoginViewController  other wise it will add splitViewController it works fine but problem is that i want that when loginViewController is added and when i press singButton on loginscreen then it should add splitViewController to window by code it does like this but when i press login singin but then app closes and when i open it again then it shows me splitViewController

here is my code

```
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"firstLaunch",nil]];

   if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) {


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(actionNotificationData:)
                                                 name:@"reloadSplit"
                                               object:nil];

        [self.window addSubview:[loginViewController view]];

  )

  else{
        [self.window addSubview:[splitViewController view]];

     }


        -(void)actionNotificationData:(NSNotification *)notification {





      [self.splitViewController removeFromParentViewController];


      window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
      if (!window) 
      window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
     [[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:splitViewController];  



      [window makeKeyAndVisible];


      }
```

here is the signInButtonAction

```
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadSplit" object:self];


           [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

My Code With

```
  self.splitViewController =[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
self.rootViewController=[[RootViewController alloc]init];
self.detailViewController=[[[FirstDetailViewController alloc]init] autorelease];
self.loginViewController=[[[LoginViewController alloc]init] autorelease];


UINavigationController *rootNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
UINavigationController *detailNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];



if ([detailNav.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav.png"];
    [detailNav.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];







}




user_Name=@"Jamshaid";

isClickedLogin=@"NO";


    userLogin=@"Logout";



self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav,detailNav,nil];
self.splitViewController.delegate=self.detailViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

First Add Your `LoginViewController` as `self.window.rootViewController`  such like

*(Here i also added UINavigationController too)*

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *loginNVController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
    loginNVController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = loginNVController;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

And Then After in `LoginViewController.m`

This is method of `signINButton`, its call when you tapped `signINButton`

```
-(void)passToSplitViewController:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.splitViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**OR**

Put Following Code at End of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
//Add the below line only if u need to populate login screen before UISplitViewController!
LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

           [self.window addSubview:splitViewController.view];

//Add the below line only if u need to populate login screen before UISplitViewController!

[splitViewController presentModalViewController:loginView animated:NO];
```

Comment: @user2240329- check my another answer :)